# How to make a menu for touchscreen (link buttons from scene to scene) with adobe flash CS6 actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, button, menu, flash-cs6

total newbie here. I've been using mouse events to link the menu buttons to jump from scene to scene or frame to frame, but since i want to make a menu for touchscreen, i would have to always double tap to actually activate the button. Is there anyway i can make the button respond with just one tap of a finger.

I've been using this code to jump from scene

```
movieClip_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

Sorry like this?

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

button_2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);

function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

Should be correct?

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

movieClip_3.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, TapHandler);

function TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 3");
}
```

Comment: "*like this?*", you have to try it! With the `TouchEvent` in place, does it work? Note that in your original  code you invoke `gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");` on `this.root` whereas in your new code, you invoke it on "nothing", which is the same as invoking it on `this`, which may or may not be the same as the previous `this.root`.

Comment: it still doesnt seem to work, do i actually have to try it on a touch screen? does clicking on it with a mouse not work?

Comment: Well, getting it to work on a touch screen is you goal, so yes, please try it on a touch screen.

Comment: dang i cant test it on a touch screen yet, but theoratically that third code should be correct? yes? sorry im really new to this.

Comment: Again, both might be actually **the same thing** depending on what your structure is. Just try them.

Comment: @Mint when I tried making my first AS3-based Android app (**.apk** file), I tested some old AS3 code that used mouse clicks. The clicks were automatically considered as single "taps". So, theoretically, even your first code should work on a real Android device...

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener for events of type [`TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#TOUCH_TAP).

Comment: Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

button_2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);

function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
{
 gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}
Something like this? but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: please do not post large chunks of code in comments. Instead add the code to your question at the end.